# A left Join under condition that the Inner Join is true SQL- MS- ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

In joining two sub-query (sub1 and sub2) I have two cases. Case1:there is at least a not null value in sub2.fldvalue and sub2.fldvalue _Override. In this case I want to keep all the values of sub1.Bloomb_Allocation, so I need LEFT JOIN. Case2: all the values in sub2.fldValue and sub2.fldValue_Override are null. In this case I do not want to keep the values of sub1.Bloomb_Allocation, so I need an INNER JOIN.  :

Query result CASE 1 (with isin= 'LU1956838830'):

```
SELECT  sub1.BB_allocation AS cln1 , sub2.fldValue AS cln2, sub2.fldValue_Override AS cln3
FROM( 
(SELECT Bloomb_Allocation, BB_allocation, ordine FROM dbBloomFields WHERE Bloomb_Blk='Asset Type') AS sub1 
Left Join 
(SELECT blkName, fldValue, fldValue_Override FROM  dbSecurityMacroAllocation  WHERE isin= 'LU1956838830') AS sub2 
ON sub1.BB_Allocation=sub2.blkName)
GROUP BY  sub1.BB_allocation  , sub2.fldValue , sub2.fldValue_Override, sub1.ordine
ORDER BY sub1.ordine
```

| cln1 | cln2 | cln3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cash and Other | NULL | NULL |
| Bond | NULL | NULL |
| Equity | 100 | NULL |
| Alternative | NULL | NULL |
| n/c | NULL | NULL |

with:
sub1:

| Bloomb_Allocation | BB_allocation | ordine |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alternative | Alternative | 4 |
| Bond | Bond | 2 |
| Cash and Other | Cash and Other | 1 |
| Equity | Equity | 3 |
| MoneyMarket | Cash and Other | 1 |
| n/c | n/c | 5 |

sub2

| blkName | fldValue | fldValue_Override |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Equity | 100 | Null |

Query result CASE 2 (Keeping LEFT JOIN with isin= 'abcd123456', not present in the table dbSecurityMacroAllocation):

```
SELECT  sub1.BB_allocation AS cln1 , sub2.fldValue AS cln2, sub2.fldValue_Override AS cln3
FROM( 
(SELECT Bloomb_Allocation, BB_allocation, ordine FROM dbBloomFields WHERE Bloomb_Blk='Asset Type') AS sub1 
Left Join 
(SELECT blkName, fldValue, fldValue_Override FROM  dbSecurityMacroAllocation  WHERE isin= 'abcd123456') AS sub2 
ON sub1.BB_Allocation=sub2.blkName)
GROUP BY  sub1.BB_allocation  , sub2.fldValue , sub2.fldValue_Override, sub1.ordine
ORDER BY sub1.ordine
```

| cln1 | cln2 | cln3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cash and Other | NULL | NULL |
| Bond | NULL | NULL |
| Equity | NULL | NULL |
| Alternative | NULL | NULL |
| n/c | NULL | NULL |

with:
sub1:

| Bloomb_Allocation | BB_allocation | ordine |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alternative | Alternative | 4 |
| Bond | Bond | 2 |
| Cash and Other | Cash and Other | 1 |
| Equity | Equity | 3 |
| MoneyMarket | Cash and Other | 1 |
| n/c | n/c | 5 |

sub2

| blkName | fldValue | fldValue_Override |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | Null |

How can I write the query to get the result for the Case 2 like:

| cln1 | cln2 | cln3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | NULL |

Comment: Why do you change the names of the columns?  The logic is really hard to follow . . . and you should show the results you want.  And what do you mean "the query results should be NULL"?  `NULL` is a value in a column.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make an INNER JOIN (only return the rows that match in the two subqueries), instead of a LEFT JOIN (returns all records from the left subquery and the matching records from the right subquery). Let me know if I am right.

```
SELECT sub1.BB_allocation AS cln1, 
       sub2.fldValue AS cln2, 
       sub2.fldValue_Override AS cln3

FROM (SELECT Bloomb_Allocation, BB_allocation, ordine FROM dbBloomFields WHERE Bloomb_Blk='Asset Type') AS sub1 

INNER JOIN (SELECT blkName, fldValue, fldValue_Override FROM  dbSecurityMacroAllocation  WHERE isin= 'LU1956838830') AS sub2 ON sub1.BB_Allocation = sub2.blkName

GROUP BY  sub1.BB_allocation, sub2.fldValue, sub2.fldValue_Override, sub1.ordine
ORDER BY sub1.ordine;
```

Your query result is wrong, because if you make a LEFT JOIN sub1 and sub2 queries by `sub1.BB_Allocation = sub2.blkName`, result cln2 value on row two should be NULL, and not "bond".

You could do the query that way too:

```
SELECT  sub1.BB_allocation AS cln1, 
        sub2.fldValue AS cln2, 
        sub2.fldValue_Override AS cln3
        
FROM dbBloomFields AS sub1
INNER JOIN dbSecurityMacroAllocation AS sub2 ON sub1.BB_Allocation = sub2.blkName
WHERE sub1.Bloomb_Blk = 'Asset Type' AND sub2.isin = 'LU1956838830'
GROUP BY  sub1.BB_allocation, sub2.fldValue, sub2.fldValue_Override, sub1.ordine
ORDER BY sub1.ordine;
```

You can try something like this to resolve CASE 1 and CASE 2:

First I make an UNION between sub1 and sub2 queries if sub2 has any row, then I make a left join to get the rest of sub2 values, and finally I make an INNER JOIN.

If sub2 return none row, then the result will be empty. If sub2 return at least one row, so the result will be a left join between sub1 and sub2.

Maybe there is a better solution, but it is the first solution I had.

```
SELECT  sub1.BB_allocation AS cln1, 
        sub2.fldValue AS cln2, 
        sub2.fldValue_Override AS cln3
        
FROM dbBloomFields AS sub1
INNER JOIN (

    SELECT u1.blkName, lj1.fldValue, lj1.fldValue_Override
    FROM (

        SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(blkName) > 0 FROM  dbSecurityMacroAllocation WHERE isin = 'LU1956838830') THEN BB_allocation ELSE NULL END AS blkName
        FROM dbBloomFields WHERE Bloomb_Blk='Asset Type'

        UNION

        SELECT blkName FROM dbSecurityMacroAllocation WHERE isin = 'LU1956838830' ) AS u1

    LEFT JOIN dbSecurityMacroAllocation AS lj1 ON u1.blkName = lj1.blkName) sub2 ON sub1.BB_Allocation = sub2.blkName

WHERE sub1.Bloomb_Blk = 'Asset Type'
GROUP BY  sub1.BB_allocation, sub2.fldValue, sub2.fldValue_Override, sub1.ordine
ORDER BY sub1.ordine;
```

Comment: You right there is NULL not Bond in the query result in cln2. Thanks for the alternative query as well. Is there a performance difference between the tow versions, should I prefer one more then the other?. Regarding the main question I want to make LEFT JOIN  if there at least a not NULL value in sub2.fldValue, but I need INNER JOIN  if ALL the values of sub2.fldValue are NULL. So I don't want to show values in cnl1 if the values of sub2.fldValue are all NULL

Comment: When you said "I need INNER JOIN if ALL the values of sub2.fldValue are NULL" this mean that in query sub2, can be a row with blkName and fldValue NULL? I think my query two has better performance because it avoid subqueries.

Comment: So you have two cases:
CASE 1 (when there is at least a NOT NULL sub2.fldValue value [you need LEFT JOIN] (your example data).
CASE 2 (when all sub2.fldValue values are NULL [you need INNER JOIN].
Could you add example data to CASE 2 (sub1 and sub2 queries example data, and the DESIRED RESULT).

Comment: I updated my question with your indications. Thanx

Comment: I add to my response a possible solution, please check it and let me know if it worked. I am not sure because I don't know your tables structure.